# Speed up conditional R loop with c/c++ or vectorization

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, rcpp

I need to create a matrix containing covariate values conditional on other variables in the dataset. Here is a self contained example of my current solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(microbenchmark)
data(heart, package = "survival")
data <- heart

# Number of unique subjects
n.sub <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% n_groups()
# Unique failure times
fail.time <- data %>% filter(event == 1) %>% distinct(stop) %>% arrange(stop) %>% .$stop
# Number of unique failure times
n.fail.time <- length(fail.time)

# Pre-fill matrix. Will be filled with covariate values.
mat <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n.sub, ncol = n.fail.time)
# Run loop
for(i in 1:n.sub) { # Number of subjects
  data.subject <- data[data$id == i, ] # subsetting here provides nice speed-up
  for(j in 1:n.fail.time) { # Number of failure times.
    value <- subset(data.subject, (start < fail.time[j]) & (stop >= fail.time[j]), select = transplant, drop = TRUE)
    if(length(value) == 0) { # An early event or censor will return empty value. Assign to zero.
      mat[i, j] <- 0
    }
    else {
      mat[i, j] <- value # True value
    }
  }
}
```

This is too slow for datasets with thousands of observations. I don't know how to best vectorize this with R code and I don't know enough c/c++ to utilize Rcpp. How can this example be sped up using one of those (or other) options?

It looks like the `src/aalen.c` file in the [timereg package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timereg/index.html) may have a c solution for something that is similar to my problem. See the code around the lines with `if ((start[c]<time) && (stop[c]>=time))`. Although that may just be my ignorance of c/programming showing.

Comment: I don't really know R but I can read some of the lines and tell some equivalent C.  Is there a way to use Rcpp to convert the libraries?

Comment: Once it's in C, the vectorization part isn't too hard.

Comment: @JeremiahDicharry: No, there isn't a way to auto-convert libraries. Rcpp is not an R-to-C(++) compiler but "merely" a rather useful piece of glue.  With some extras (like vectorisation).

Comment: @kzoo: this is an interesting read - [High performance functions with Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html)

Comment: @JeremiahDicharry There is also plenty of primary documentation.

Comment: There may be an unintended behaviour in this code, namely that the assignment of the matrix element value from `value` takes the integer value of the factor, not the label of the factor. This results in a `mat` matrix of 0, 1, 2. Is that what you are expecting? Or did you just want a matrix of 0s and 1s?

Comment: @KenBenoit Currently the behavior is fine either way. Although it is something I need to make sure is standardized in the future. Thanks for reminding of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing similar choices with moving to C++ to speed up a different problem, but I ended up turning to the R packages that are already implemented efficiently in C++ and using those.  Here, what you want is a package called **data.table**.

If you are new to R, this might be hard to follow, but there is good documentation for the data.table package through the vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).  To get a feel for what is happening below, you will probably gain insight from stepping through the code for the reduced dataset I tested this on (see the bottom of the answer), and monitoring the objects as they change values.  The key to the speed improvement is using the fast assignment methods of data.table, and performing only vectorized operations.

My solution is below.  Note that I am not sure you want the 0, 1, 2 values, but I am happy to change the code to produce 0, 1 if that is what you intended.

```
require(data.table)

dataDT <- data.table(data[, c("id", "start", "stop", "transplant")])
# add a serial number for each id
dataDT[, idObs := 1:length(start), by = id ]
# needed because transplant is a factor in the heart dataset
dataDT[, transplant := as.integer(transplant)]

# create a "long" format data.table of subjects, observation number, and start/stop times
matDT <- data.table(subject = rep(1:n.sub, each = n.fail.time * max(dataDT$idObs)),
                    idObs = rep(1:max(dataDT$idObs), max(dataDT$idObs), n.sub * max(dataDT$idObs)),
                    fail.time = rep(fail.time, each = max(dataDT$idObs)))

# merge in start and stop times
setkey(matDT, subject, idObs)
setkey(dataDT, id, idObs)
matDT <- dataDT[matDT]

# eliminate missings (for which no 2nd observation took place)
matDT <- matDT[!is.na(transplant)]

# this replicates the "value" assignment in the loop
matDT[, value := transplant * ((start < fail.time) & (stop >= fail.time))]

# sum on the ids by fail time
matDT2 <- matDT[, list(matVal = sum(value)), by = list(id, fail.time)]

# convert to a matrix
mat2 <- matrix(matDT2$matVal, ncol = ncol(mat), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(1:n.sub, fail.time))
```

This is many times faster than your code, according to `microbenchmark()`, where the first method is your code from the question:

```
        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 310.503535 339.364159 396.287178 354.292829 406.937216 762.28838   100
   7.113083   7.420517   9.436973   7.788479   9.426443  32.50355   100
```

To show the output, I tested this on the first six rows of your `data` object.  This provides a good example as the third and fourth patients (id = 3, 4) have two observations each, before and after transplant.

```
data <- heart[1:6, ]
```

and then I added row and column labels to your `mat` object:

```
colnames(mat) <- fail.time
rownames(mat) <- 1:n.sub
mat
##   6 16 39 50
## 1 1  1  1  1
## 2 1  0  0  0
## 3 2  2  0  0
## 4 1  1  2  0
```

Here you can see that the new `mat2` is identical:

```
mat2
##   6 16 39 50
## 1 1  1  1  1
## 2 1  0  0  0
## 3 2  2  0  0
## 4 1  1  2  0
all.equal(mat, mat2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I converted your solution to dplyr as I'm more familiar with that, however your solution is still the fastest!

Comment: What is `length(start)`? Isn't this should just be `dataDT[, idObs := seq_len(.N), by = id ]`? Also shouldn't the conversion from a factor should be `as.integer(as.character(transplant))`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I questioned that part also. I interpreted it to be an easy way to grab the maximum number of times an `id` _could_ be repeated. Your code may be better. Your factor conversion produces more intuitive results, however for the case where the factors are character strings, returning the integer factor level is better.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, the `seq_len(.N)` is an equivalent but more data.table consistent solution. On the coercion of the `transplant` factor, I didn't coerce the transplant to character first because the solution contains the levels (1s and 2s), and wrapping the `as.integer()` around `as.character()` made this 0s and 1s. (Which I found curious, hence my query to the OP.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a dplyr version of @KenBenoit solution (see the `dplyr.matrix` function). Below is the code to test all three methods.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(survival)
library(microbenchmark)
data(heart, package = "survival")
data <- heart

old.matrix <- function(data) {
  # Number of unique subjects
  n.subjects <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% n_groups()
  # Unique failure times
  fail.time <- data %>% filter(event == 1) %>% distinct(stop) %>% arrange(stop) %>% .$stop
  # Number of unique failure times
  n.fail.time <- length(fail.time)

  # Pre-fill matrix. Will be filled with covariate values.
  mat <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n.subjects, ncol = n.fail.time)
  # Run loop
  for(i in 1:n.subjects) { # Number of subjects
    data.subject <- data[data$id == i, ] # subsetting here provides nice speed-up
    for(j in 1:n.fail.time) { # Number of failure times.
      value <- subset(data.subject, (start < fail.time[j]) & (stop >= fail.time[j]), select = transplant, drop = TRUE)
      if(length(value) == 0) { # An early event or censor will return empty value. Assign to zero.
        mat[i, j] <- 0
      }
      else {
        mat[i, j] <- value # True value
      }
    }
  }
  mat
}

dplyr.matrix <- function(data) {
  # Number of unique subjects
  n.subjects <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% n_groups()
  # Unique failure times
  fail.time <- data %>% filter(event == 1) %>% distinct(stop) %>% arrange(stop) %>% .$stop
  # Number of unique failure times
  n.fail.time <- length(fail.time)

  # add a serial number for each id
  data <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(id.serial = 1:length(start))
  # needed because transplant is a factor in the heart dataset
  data$transplant <- as.integer(data$transplant)
  # create a "long" format data.frame of subjects, observation number, and start/stop times
  data.long <- data.frame(
    id = rep(1:n.subjects, each = n.fail.time * max(data$id.serial)),
    id.serial = rep(1:max(data$id.serial), max(data$id.serial), n.subjects * max(data$id.serial)),
    fail.time = rep(fail.time, each = max(data$id.serial))
  )
  # merge in start and stop times
  data.merge <- left_join(data.long, data[, c("start", "stop", "transplant", "id", "id.serial")], by = c("id", "id.serial"))
  # eliminate missings (for which no 2nd observation took place)
  data.merge <- na.omit(data.merge)
  # this replicates the "value" assignment in the loop
  data.merge <- data.merge %>% mutate(value = transplant * ((start < fail.time) & (stop >= fail.time)))
  # sum on the ids by fail time
  data.merge <- data.merge %>% group_by(id, fail.time) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))
  # convert to a matrix
  data.matrix <- matrix(data.merge$value, ncol = n.fail.time, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(1:n.subjects, fail.time))
  data.matrix
}

data.table.matrix <- function(data) {
  # Number of unique subjects
  n.subjects <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% n_groups()
  # Unique failure times
  fail.time <- data %>% filter(event == 1) %>% distinct(stop) %>% arrange(stop) %>% .$stop
  # Number of unique failure times
  n.fail.time <- length(fail.time)

  dataDT <- data.table(data[, c("id", "start", "stop", "transplant")])
  # add a serial number for each id
  dataDT[, idObs := 1:length(start), by = id ]
  # needed because transplant is a factor in the heart dataset
  dataDT[, transplant := as.integer(transplant)]
  # create a "long" format data.table of subjects, observation number, and start/stop times
  matDT <- data.table(subject = rep(1:n.subjects, each = n.fail.time * max(dataDT$idObs)),
                      idObs = rep(1:max(dataDT$idObs), max(dataDT$idObs), n.subjects * max(dataDT$idObs)),
                      fail.time = rep(fail.time, each = max(dataDT$idObs)))
  # merge in start and stop times
  setkey(matDT, subject, idObs)
  setkey(dataDT, id, idObs)
  matDT <- dataDT[matDT]
  # eliminate missings (for which no 2nd observation took place)
  matDT <- matDT[!is.na(transplant)]
  # this replicates the "value" assignment in the loop
  matDT[, value := transplant * ((start < fail.time) & (stop >= fail.time))]
  # sum on the ids by fail time
  matDT2 <- matDT[, list(matVal = sum(value)), by = list(id, fail.time)]
  # convert to a matrix
  mat2 <- matrix(matDT2$matVal, ncol = n.fail.time, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(1:n.subjects, fail.time))
  mat2
}

all(dplyr.matrix(data) == old.matrix(data))
all(dplyr.matrix(data) == data.table.matrix(data))

microbenchmark(
  old.matrix(data),
  dplyr.matrix(data),
  data.table.matrix(data),
  times = 50
)
```

The output from microbenchmark:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
        old.matrix(data) 325.949687 328.102482 333.20923 329.39368 331.28305 373.44774    50   c
      dplyr.matrix(data)  17.586146  18.317833  20.04662  18.95724  19.62431  60.15858    50  b 
 data.table.matrix(data)   9.464045   9.892281  10.72819  10.29394  11.44812  12.67738    50 a
```

The above results correspond with a dataset of around 100 observations. When I tested this on a dataset with around 1000 observations, `data.table` started pulling away even more.

```
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval cld
        old.matrix(data) 13095.7836 13114.1858 13162.5019 13134.0735 13150.217 13318.2496     5   c
      dplyr.matrix(data)  1067.1942  1075.5291  1149.0789  1166.8951  1197.998  1237.7787     5  b 
 data.table.matrix(data)   104.5133   155.2074   159.6794   159.6364   166.764   212.2758     5 a
```

`data.table` is the winner for now.